# How can I store data in sql database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

What is the correct C# code to write/store data from an ASP.NET app to a MS SQL Database?

Comment: Too generic question, read documentation about ADO.NET or .NET data access methods.

Comment: Which database are you using? What and how do you want to write to the dataase?

Comment: Also accept some answers to your previous questions if you want to be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: do you have sample code?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways you can write/store data to sql database. But to give you a heads start you can check this out

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

set `varchar(50)` or date any SQL Datatype, in SQL Server
In webform set calander control name "Calander1" 
then,
try This Code to save Date into SQL:

```
try
{
    string Releasedate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.ToString();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO mydb (date) VALUES ('"+Releasedate+"')", sqlcon);
    sqlcon.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{               
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    sqlcon.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your question is a very generic. But a very basic way to select, insert, update and delete data to a sql server database is through SqlCommand object. The site given [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson03.aspx) will give you an idea of the same. This site also contains sample code.